# delete statement takes unreasonable time to finish or fails on MAC with OS neo4j 3.2.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

MAX OS X 10.11.6, neo4j 3.2.0

a simple query in a database without relations (relations were deleted with `MATCH ()-[a]-() delete a`);

The setup:

```
match ()-[a]-() return count(a);

+----------+
| count(a) |
+----------+
| 576333   |
+----------+
```

Then I wish to clean up the database:

```
match (a) delete a;
```

and after 5 minutes I get

> There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database.

However, this helps:

```
MATCH (n) with n limit 100000 delete (n) ;
```

> 0 rows available after 302 ms, consumed after another 0 ms
>
> Deleted 100000 nodes

Could someone comment such behavior of the DATABASE? Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you want to delete all your data, please consider to use `DETACH DELETE` instead of the `DELETE` command.

This will delete all relationships of your nodes, and then delete the node. Otherwise with `MATCH (n) with n limit 100000 delete (n)` you will only delete orphan nodes.

All data modifications in a transaction are kept in memory. So if you try to delete `10G of data` at once, you will need `10G of RAM`.

To avoid to add some memory to the java heap for resolving this problem, you have to batch your operations.

One way, is to repeat this query until its result is `0` : `MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT 100000 DETACH DELETE n RETURN count(*)`.

There is some helpers on the APOC project that can help you to do it like `apoc.periodic.commit`.
Take a look here : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_further_functions

Cheers

Comment: DETACH  makes no difference as there are no relations already;
isn't it odd to have e.g., 10G transactions for 10G nodes for such trivial case?

Comment: An ACID / transactional database has to keep in memory all the data you are working on, for locks, rollback etc  functionalities.

Comment: logisima, does neo4j really keeps all in memory? 
are there references?
 as I see it, all databases should have logs on disk  or at least, swap their in - memory logs to disk if necessary

Comment: It's not the transaction log file, it's about all the data you are modifying during a transaction.  Until you have commit your data, other users must not seen your modifications. FS are slow, that's why it's in memory.